# Failed in loading csv data to Elasticsearch, translation issue

Tags: java, ruby, csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to import CSV file to elastic file, but it is failed and threw an error

> Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main",
>   :exception=>#,
>   :backtrace=>["/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.6.1/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.5.0/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:222:in
>   `block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1428:in`each'",
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.6.1/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.5.0/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:220:in
>   `register'",
>   "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractFilterDelegatorExt.java:56:in`
>   register'",
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.6.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:200:in
>   `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1814:in`
>   each'",
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.6.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:199:in
>   `register_plugins'",
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.6.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:502:in`
>   maybe_setup_out_plugins'",
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.6.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:212:in
>   `start_workers'",
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.6.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:154:in`
>   run'",
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.6.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:109:in
>   `block in start'"],
>   "pipeline.sources"=>["/Users/user/Document/Esk-Data/xudaxia.conf"],
>   :thread=>"#"}

Below is the **conf** file

```
input
{
    file{
    path => ["/test.csv"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter{
    csv{
        separator => ","
         columns => ["comment_time","comment", "id", "video_time"]
       }
    mutate{
        convert => {
            "comment_time" => "date_time"
            "comment" => "string"
            "id" => "integer"
            "video_time" => "float"
      }
    }
}
output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "test"
    }
}
```

**test.csv**

```
comment_time         comment        id        video_time
2020/03/22 15:59:41  バイ             a        123.100
2020/03/22 15:59:45  บาย             b        100.100
2020/04/22 15:59:50  ByeBye          c        80.210
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the documentation the option `date_time` doesn't exist for convert action on `mutate` plugin - doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert).
However this plugin is used to cast a type into another one, that it isn't your use case. If `comment_time` is not recognized as date field you should trasform it with `date` plugin - doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html).

So you should remove this block:

```
mutate{
    convert => {
        "comment_time" => "date_time"
        "comment" => "string"
        "id" => "integer"
        "video_time" => "float"
  }
}
```

and replace it with this one:

```
date {
    match => [ "comment_time", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
}
```